# How can i search in an array the value of my key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, i'm getting the duration by POST (for instance 6) and i want to get the price.

```
$duration = $_POST['duration']; // Can be 6, 1 or 3

    // Constantes pour l'abonnement
     $suscribe = array(
        'prices' => array(
            1=>10,
            3=>25,
            6=>50
            )
        );
```

So i want to get the price value in a PHP variable, 50 . 
Thanks .

Comment: `echo $suscribe['prices'][$_POST['duration']];` (perhaps?)

Comment: `$suscribe['prices'][$_POST['duration']]` ?

Comment: I 'm confused. You learned the array syntax without also learning how to index into one?

Answer (score 2):

use following code:

```
$price_6 = $subscribe['prices'][6];

print_r($price_6);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a normal array access (saying nothing for sanitizing this $_POST variable):

```
echo $subscribe['prices'][$_POST['duration']];
```

Answer (score 0):

do like

```
$duration = (int) $_POST['duration']; // Can be 6, 1 or 3

echo $suscribe['prices'][$duration];
```